# How can I add this property to JsonConvert?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

This is the code I have:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
```

How can I add also this property?

```
new IsoDateTimeConverter()
```

Because it prints DateTime in a way I don't like. Usually I do:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the converter to the `Converters` collection on the [`JsonSerializerSettings`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) object.

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new IsoDateTimeConverter() }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, settings);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kxprpr

Comment: JsonSerializerSettings doesn't contains a definition of Formatting.

Comment: Not true. See [the documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm).